# ArangoDB: Syntax error Unexpected For declaration

Tags: for-loop, arangodb

in the following query I want to traverse a graph and get a list of fraud nodes and then I want to get all the traversals between those fraud nodes in the graph.

Fraud nodes I want to store in the variable lstofnodes.
How to solve this error?

```
let lstofnodes=(for doc in Account  
    filter doc.fraud == true
        for v in 1..3 outbound doc graph "G1"
            return distinct v._id)
            return lstofnodes
            for vertex in 1..3 outbound lstofndes  graph "G1"
                return distinct vertex._id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try (the first return seems wrong, but cannot verify without data)

```
let lstofnodes=(for doc in Account  
filter doc.fraud == true
    for v in 1..3 outbound doc graph "G1"
        return distinct v._id)
        FOR startnode IN lstofnodes
        for vertex in 1..3 outbound startnode  graph "G1"
            return distinct vertex._id
```